# How to declare same style for @media and descendant selector?

Tags: less, mixins, less-mixins

I need to define same style for elements under a media query and descendant by another class.

Perfect solution in LESS **could be** the following [pseudo-code]:

```
.foo
{
  color:red;

  .example &,
  @media (min-width:800px)
  {
    color:blue;
  }
}
```

that should be desirable that would be compiled into:

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.example .foo {
  color: blue;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .foo {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

THIS SYNTAX IS INCORRECT but, do you have some suggestion to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to *@seven-phases-max* suggestion, I finally found a possible solution using **[Detached Ruleset](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature)**:

```
@screen-xs: 480px;
@screen-sm: 769px;
@screen-md: 992px;
@screen-lg: 1200px;

.MEDIAQUERY(@only-media, @min-max, @size, @RULES) 
{
  @screen-width:~"@{screen-@{size}}";

  @mediaQuery: ~"screen and (@{min-max}-width: @{screen-width})";

  @media @mediaQuery { @RULES(); }

  & when (@only-media = false) {
    .@{size} &       { @RULES(); }  
  }
}

.foo_media-and-class
{
  color:red;

  .MEDIAQUERY(@only-media:false, @min-max:max, @size:md,
    { 
        color:blue;
    }
  );

  .MEDIAQUERY(@only-media:false,  @min-max:min, @size:lg,
    { 
        color:yellow;
    }
  );
}

.foo_only-media
{
  color:red;

  .MEDIAQUERY(@only-media:true,  @min-max:max, @size:md,
    { 
        color:blue;
    }
  );

  .MEDIAQUERY(@only-media:true,  @min-max:min, @size:lg,
    { 
        color:yellow;
    }
  );
}
```

This solution go beyond and offer other options:

- Possibility to set a custom value of screen width for media query,
- Pass `MIN/MAX` value of property used in media query (Try to pass "`max`" instead of "`min`" calling .MEDIAQUERY mixin)
- Toggling generation of simple media query or media query + descendant selector, through `@only-media` boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, selectors and `@media` queries are too different language entities (despite having similar `{}` syntax) so you can't combine those with comma like in your example.

So to get it DRY (assuming that shared style has more than one property of course) you'll need a mixin (or sort of), for example:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
    .somename() {
        color: blue;
    }

    .example &                {.somename}
    @media (min-width: 800px) {.somename}
}
```

Also see [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) examples (if you need even more generic solution).

Answer (score 0):

I think your comma might be causing the error.

```
.foo {
   color:red;
   .example & {
   color:blue;
     @media (min-width:800px) {
      color:blue;
     }
   }
}
```

This is proper syntax to output the following:

```
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.example .foo {
  color:blue;
}
 @media (min-width:800px) {
  .example .foo {
    color:blue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aibrean, your solution is not exactly what I need, infact you get `.example .foo` inside media query, while my desired output is sglightly different as you can see in my question