# LESS: render content of a media query in class (fallback)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, less, media-queries

do you know if there is a way to render the exact same content of a media query into a class in LESS?

To explain my case:
I'm doing mobile first and trying to avoid overrides with media queries. Unfortunately this ends up excluding ie8 and below since most of the styles for desktop are into a media query. I'm serving only the desktop page to IE8 (fixed width).

So at the end of the day I would like to combine this:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    color: red;
}
.ie8 & {
    color: red;
}
```

Chaining it with comma doesn't work since it's not valid (@media (min-width: 769px),.ie8 {}).
In Sass I can achieve this over a mixin with @content. But I wasn't able to do this in LESS.

Does anyone has a workaround how to do this in LESS? Somehow with a loop maybe?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26891238/2712740

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature Not the same kind of flexibility but close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question and after a suggestion about detached ruleset, I developed a possible solution explained [**here** in details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891238/how-to-declare-same-style-for-media-and-descendant-selector?answertab=active#tab-top).

Major PROs of this are the following:

- Possibility to set a custom value of screen width for media query,
- Pass `MIN/MAX` value of property used in media query (Try to pass "`max`" instead of "`min`" calling .MEDIAQUERY mixin)
- Toggling generation of simple media query or media query + descendant selector, through `@only-media` boolean.